# Calling another function which is in the list of exportable functions

Tags: c#, dll, dllexport

I have written a library which has some functions that are being exported. An example:

```
[DllExport("Test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static void Test() {
    MessageBox.Show("Test 1");
}

[DllExport("Test2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static void TestTwo() {
    MessageBox.Show("Test 2");
    Test();
    //TestThree();
}

public static void TestThree() {
    MessageBox.Show("Test 3");
}
```

When i call `Test` from an external application (Delphi) it works ok and i get the message box.
When i call `Test2`, i get the External exception in Delphi. Exception is thrown right away, it doesnt even show me the message box `Test 2`.
When i call `Test2` which in turn calls `TestThree`, which is not exportable function, it runs ok and i get both, message box `Test 2` and `Test 3`.

Why can't i call other exported functions inside my DLL? Is there any way i CAN do it?

**EDIT 1:**

At this point i could achieve what i need by doing the following:
Created another non-exportable function `Test_Local()`, moved all of the code from `Test`. Now instead of calling `Test()` from `TestTwo` i call `Test_Local()`, function `Test` also calls `Test_Local();`

Everything runs ok until `Test_Local()` tries to run any other exportable function.

So it is somehow bad to call exportable function inside another exportable function and it doesn't matter how many layers of non-exportable functions are there between them.

Comment: I think you answered the question yourself. I'd just recommend to wrap the exportable methods to a separate class and only put one line of code to each of them. That line would be a call to the "actual" executive code. This way it'll be always clear which methods are "exposed" and that you never call exportable methods within your regular code.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that occurs to me is that the export name and the local name for the method is the same. Have you tried changing the local name of the method?

```
[DllExport("Test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static void TestOne() {
    MessageBox.Show("Test 1");
}

[DllExport("Test2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static void TestTwo() {
    MessageBox.Show("Test 2");
    TestOne();
    //TestThree();
}

public static void TestThree() {
    MessageBox.Show("Test 3");
}
```

I have not tested this.